# Update vs Outdate

Tags: etymology, antonyms, prefixes

I'm not sure if this question belongs on English SE, but the following question is about word origins.

Let's take two words: **update** and **outdate**.

> **Update** means to make (something) more modern or up to date.
>
> **Outdate** means to to make out of date : make obsolete.

So, we can say, more or less, that **update** and **outdate** are opposites or antonyms.

So, why are the prefixes **up** and **out** rather than **up** and **down** or **in** and **out**?

> Wouldn't **update/downdate** or **indate/outdate** make more sense? Where
>   did the origin of the prefixes **up/out** come from?

Comment: Sorry but no. It sounds as though it should, and “Update” does not mean to make (something) more modern or up to date nor, really, anything like that.
To “update” broadly means simply to replace an old with a new value.
Do you see the difference?
Outdate would, mechanically, mean to make out of date or obsolete but it doesn’t. You might find a dictionary which suggests otherwise but idiomatically, “outdate” as a verb has only past tenses: it is/was/became/was outdated.
If you think “I will/you might outdate this/that/the other” has a place in English, please explain how.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Google says update is that exact definition...

Comment: Really? What, exactly, did you mean by "update is that exact definition"?

Is it possible you're not sure what "update" and "outdate" mean?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin like if you look up "update meaning" on google you get exactly what I wrote above :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because **update** comes from **bring up to date** while **outdate** from **make out of date**.

As you see, their etymologies do not really go hand in hand.

Comment: Ah I see that actually makes a lot of sense! Thanks :D